# I want to select 300 rows from a table and insert them again into the same table

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have a table [Emp] with the following columns:

EmpID,
EmpName,
EmpLastName,
EmpSalary,
Month,
Year,
ModDate

I want to use approximately 300 records from a previous month to create 300 new records into the same table with the same values except the month attribute which I want to modify during the insertion statement.

I want to use MS Access + vb6 for this purpose.

I will really appreciate it if you could help me to solve this problem.

The query I am trying to execute is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Emp ( EmpID, EmpName, EmpLastName, EmpSalary, [Month], [Year], ModDate)
SELECT Emp.EmpID, Emp.EmpName, Emp.EmpLastName, Emp.EmpSalary, 4 AS Expr1, Emp.[Year], Now() AS Expr2
FROM Emp
WHERE (((Emp.[Year])=2013) AND ((Emp.[Month])=3))
```

Comment: Is there something significant about the "300" value, or is that just the (approximate) number of employees? In other words, do you want to copy records for *all* employees, even if there are >300 of them?

Comment: Yes your're right it is just the approximate number of employees.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to copy all the employees from the preview month the the current one let say copy all employees from january, modify the month to Febrary and insert them all into the same table

Comment: My answer assumed that the [Month] column was integer (1 for "January", 2 for "February", etc.). One of your comments to my answer suggests that your [Month] column is text. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, the month is text, but I changed it to number and the same error happend.

Comment: I updated my answer to handle [Month] as a Text column.

Comment: I have tried the new query and the result is the same. I am using MS access 2003 query, just to let you know.

Comment: Is [Year] also Text? If so, change it to Number (Integer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essence of what you want to achieve is a query like the following, which SELECTs the records for March 2013 and INSERTs them into the same table for April 2013:

```
INSERT INTO Emp ( EmpID, EmpName, EmpLastName, EmpSalary, [Month], [Year], ModDate )
SELECT Emp.EmpID, Emp.EmpName, Emp.EmpLastName, Emp.EmpSalary, 4 AS Expr1, Emp.[Year], Now() AS Expr2
FROM Emp
WHERE (((Emp.[Year])=2013) AND ((Emp.[Month])=3))
```

**[edit]**

The above query assumed that [Month] was a Numeric column. If [Month] is a Text column then the corresponding query would be

```
INSERT INTO Emp ( EmpID, EmpName, EmpLastName, EmpSalary, [Month], [Year], ModDate )
SELECT Emp.EmpID, Emp.EmpName, Emp.EmpLastName, Emp.EmpSalary, 'April' AS Expr1, Emp.[Year], Now() AS Expr2
FROM Emp
WHERE (((Emp.[Year])=2013) AND ((Emp.[Month])='March'))
```

Note, however, that storing month *numbers* is **much preferred** to storing month *names*. Keeping that column as Text will likely cause unnecessary complications down the road.

**[/edit]**

Your VB6 code can construct such a string, replacing the hard-coded values with the results of VB functions like `Year()`, `Month()`, etc. (and increment the year for December->January). Once you've constructed the SQL string you can execute it using the database connection you've established (most likely using a method like `.Execute`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will test what you suggested. As for the year and month I will input those values using a vb text box or combobox.

Comment: When I try to excute the query I receive an error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Edit your question to show the query you are trying to execute.